# Как сделать запрос на 2 домена через PHP по POST?

Tags: php

Как это можно сделать?

Есть Клиент, Сервер1, Сервер2. Клиент по POST посылает запрос на Сервер1. Сервер1 обрабатывает переменные из POST и по обработанным данным делает запрос на Сревер2. Получив ответ от Сервера2, Сервер1 заканчивает обработку запроса от Клиента и выдаёт ему ответную страницу. Т.е. Сервер1 должен ответить Клиенту ТОЛЬКО после получения ответа от Сервера2 запроса со стороны Сервера1. Просьба привести какой-то пример кода.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Могу посоветовать схему, как это сделать.

1. Клиент отправил данные к примеру через ajax...
2. Тут сервак1 обработал данные и с помощью cURL отправил их на другой сервак2 и ждет, пока что-то придет от сервака2 и как только что-то пришло, сервак1 отправляет данные обратно к клиенту.

Comment: ИМХО самое нормальное решение